# How to assign or pass byte array to MWArray?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, .net-4.0, matlab-deployment

I am trying to pass an MWArray of byts to a function. The byte array get data from an mp3 file.

Now I want to assign byte array to MWArray.

My code like this

```
string lSongFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SongFilePath"].ToString();
lSongFilePath += "\\" + "Grand Piano - Fazioli - major A.wav";

FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(lSongFilePath);
try
{

     byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
     var read =  (fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)));

     MWArray[] in_Arr = new MWArray[(int)read];
     MWArray[] out_Arr = null;// = new MWArray[15];

     ChordRecognizer hj = new ChordRecognizer();
     hj.estimateTuning(4,ref out_Arr, in_Arr);
     fs.Close();


}
catch(Exception ex)
{
string s = ex.Message;
}
```

This line just mention the size of array while I want to assign data to array too. please help

```
MWArray[] in_Arr = new MWArray[(int)read];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not required, but FWIW, when combining a directory path and filename to get a full file path, you should use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)

Since you want to read the whole file into a byte array, you can use [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)

I'm having trouble finding a place that documents what MWArray would look like in C# code - specifically creating it from the byte array.  If you have a pointer to how to construct it for a single byte value, we can figure it out from there.